# Attach view only after all composed modules are activated in DurandalJS.

Tags: javascript, durandal

I have a main view with two sub-views (using DurandalJS composition). Right now, the main view's viewAttached event is firing early while my sub-views are still dealing with ajax requests. Ideally, the main view would only attach the view to the DOM and run the transition AFTER all composed sub-views have finished activating.

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>    
<div data-bind="compose: { model: 'viewmodels/subview1', activate: true }">Loading...</div>    
<div data-bind="compose: { model: 'viewmodels/subview2', activate: true }">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The most straight-forward way to handle this is to manually activate the sub-views during the activation of the main view.

Remove the activate:true from the sub-view compose bindings, and in your main VM do something like this:

```
//in main view model
var subViewModel1 = require("viewModels/subViewModel1");
var subViewModel2 = require("viewModels/subViewModel2");

function activate() {
    return $.when(
        subViewModel1.activate(),
        subViewModel2.activate()
    ).then(function () {
        //finish your main view's activation here
        ...
    });
}
```

Make sure your main VM returns a promise that only resolves when the sub-VMs have completed their activation.  Likewise, the sub-VMs should ensure that their activate function returns a promise that only resolves when the AJAX request for that sub-VM is completed.

There's a [thread in Durandal Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/durandaljs/1GNDwqiObLI) that discusses a similar concept.  If you haven't already, it's definitely worth reading up a bit on the docs also, specifically these related to your question:

- [Using Composition](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/)
- [Composition Reference](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Composition/)
- [Hooking Life-Cycle Events](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/)